# How can I compare primitive class types? Like Integer and Void?

Tags: java, class, types

I want to compare return type of a method with some classes like `int`, `void`, `String`, etc.

I used a code like this:

It always prints `"null"`.

```
Class type = m.getReturnType(); 
if (type.equals(Integer.class)) {
    System.out.print("0");
} else if (type.equals(Long.class)) {
    System.out.print("1");
} else if (type.equals(Boolean.class)) {
    System.out.print("2");
} else if (type.equals(Double.class)) {
    System.out.print("3");
} else if (type.equals(Void.class)) {
    System.out.print("4");
} else {
    System.out.print("null");
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code seems ok, but with a little problem:

```
Class type = m.getReturnType(); 
boolean result = type.equals(Integer.class);
```

`result` here will only evaluate to `true` if `m`'s returning type is of the `Integer` class.

If it is an `int` that will evaluate to `false`.

To check if the return type is also a **primitive type, you need to compare to `Integer.TYPE` (not `.class`)** and similarly to the other types.

---

So change your code from:

```
if (type.equals(Integer.class)) {
```

to

```
if (type.equals(Integer.class) || type.equals(Integer.TYPE)) {
```

and do the same for the other types. This will match methods like `Integer getAge()` and `int getAge()`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Class.TYPE`

```
if (type.equals(Integer.TYPE)) {
    ...
}
```

Since that is a `java.lang.reflect.Method` class, you cannot use `instanceof` in this case.

Comment: I tried also this but eclipse red underline ".class" and writes: Syntax error on token "class", Identifier expected"

Comment: Yes. m is a java.lang.reflect.Method

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you are comparing Wrapper types with their primitve counterparts - these are not the same.

Example:

```
interface Methods {
  int mInt();
  Integer mInteger();

  void mVoid();

}

class Sample {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Method mInt = Methods.class.getMethod("mInt", new Class[0]);
    Method mInteger = Methods.class.getMethod("mInteger", new Class[0]);
    Method mVoid = Methods.class.getMethod("mVoid", new Class[0]);


    mInt.getReturnType(); // returns int.class
    mInteger.getReturnType(); // returns Integer.class
    mVoid.getReturnType(); // returns void.class
  }
}
```